# Order dropdown alphabetically, then by specific prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to sort dropdown in alphabetical order, then by  prefix.

The prefix I want to sort by is "b: " so anything that starts with "b: " should be at the bottom.

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
  <option value="4">b: option 1</option>
  <option value="5">b: option 2</option>  
  <option value="6">c</option>
</select>
```

This is desired end result:

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
  <option value="6">c</option>
  <option value="4">b: option 1</option>
  <option value="5">b: option 2</option>  
</select>
```

I use this JavaScript code to do alphabetical sort:

```
  $("#dropdown option").sort(function(a,b) { 
    var at = $(a).text();
    var bt = $(b).text();         
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);        
  }).appendTo("#dropdown");
```

This outputs:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="4">b: option 1</option>
    <option value="5">b: option 2</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
    <option value="6">c</option>
</select>
```

But I still need to push "b: " elements to the bottom of the dropdown. How can I achieve this?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6s7r3j7/) link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another check with [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for the prefix and take the delta of the check.

```
at.startsWith(prefix) - bt.startsWith(prefix)
```

```js
var prefix = 'b:'
$("#dropdown option").sort(function(a, b) {
  var at = $(a).text();
  var bt = $(b).text();
  return at.startsWith(prefix) - bt.startsWith(prefix) || at > bt || -(at < bt);
}).appendTo("#dropdown");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
  <option value="4">b: option 1</option>
  <option value="5">b: option 2</option>  
  <option value="6">c</option>
</select>
```

For older user agents, you could use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
var prefix = 'b:'
$("#dropdown option").sort(function(a, b) {
  var at = $(a).text();
  var bt = $(b).text();
  return !at.indexOf(prefix) - !bt.indexOf(prefix) || at > bt || -(at < bt);
}).appendTo("#dropdown");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
  <option value="4">b: option 1</option>
  <option value="5">b: option 2</option>  
  <option value="6">c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That seems to do the job, but startsWith will not work in older browsers?